# Undo operation not working in Rich text [Gutenberg]

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

The Undo (ctrl + z) is not working in Rich Text but it's working in the WordPress blocks.
Am I missing some parameter somewhere?

It records everything in the history reducers when typing something in the RichText of WordPress blocks but doesn't record anything when doing the same in my block.